# Eclipse RSE or Aptana uploads going to sub-directory

Tags: eclipse, ftp, directory, aptana

When I use Eclipse Remote System Explorer or Aptana plugin to upload files, the files are placed in a sub-directory of my intended upload folder.  The sub-directory is named according to my project name.  How do I upload to the folder I intend to upload to without the files going into a sub-directory?  Thanks for your wisdom!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not speak of RSE, but in Aptana Studio everything depends on how did you setup a connection between FTP and local project. Basically, if your ftp://xyz/myproject is connected to myproject in workspace, all files will go where intended to without sub-folders.
See http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/FTP%2C+SFTP%2C+and+FTPS+Deployment for more information.

Regards,
Max

Comment: I never figured this out for RSE and I happily switched to PhpStorm once I started working more specifically with Symfony 2.